# External list edit form not shown

Tags: 2013, bcs

I created an external list using Business Connect Services. I have added operations for read list, read item and update item. Then create external list using external content type. I can display list and read item in popup mode. But cannot edit item. When editing it shows as default edit form not found.

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple mistake. You should have implemented the update method after you created the list. At the point of list creation, there was no update method. So there is no associated edit form to the list. Delete the existing list and recreate the list with the newly updated content type. This will give you the edit form.

Also if you are implementing the add, delete methods later, please follow the same instructions.